# UciError: Invalid value 3 for precision when adding value to Decimals Supported filed in Products Form

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I have a **Product** form which has a field **"Decimals Supported"**, when I enter a value and try to save it I get an error saying ***UciError: Invalid value 3 precision***. This happens only on first Save after I dismiss the error and Save it again, it works fine. And also when the value is 0 or 1 or 2 it works fine without any error, but when value is more than 2 like 3, 4, 5 and so on it gives this error.

P.S: This issue is only on **Unified Interface (UCI)** and works fine without any error on Classic Legacy Mode.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just truied to reprodice your issue on one of my trial instance and I did not faced any issue. Below screenshot for Ref.

[image]

When I add 1,2 and any other till 5 no issues.

[image]

What version are you using, below is detail from my system

[image]

Comment: I am using the same version.

Comment: try using different browser and so on.

Comment: Tried. No Luck! Thinking to raise bug with Microsoft.